# how to get the link of reddit post's content from the post link itself

Tags: python, discord.py, reddit

so i want to have a command for my discord bot which will make it so someone can text a reddit link
say

https://www.reddit.com/r/DankMemesFromSite19/comments/nu1eet/here_we_go_again/

and the bot will reply with the content of the post itself so going off the previous example

https://preview.redd.it/bsmq4shc4r371.jpg?width=461&auto=webp&s=452aedfdf3022f050f56e2c400d2d1c207c4ed50

issue is i don't know how to extract the second link from the first, and i can't find anything through google.

is there even a way to do this because i really want to add this feature

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code to share with us?

Comment: unfortunately i do not. all i have tried is searching through all the coding websites i know, and i didn't find anything. maybe this isn't the right place to ask the question but i really have nothing from beforehand